# SignalR freezing all subsequent http requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, signalr

I am trying to use SignalR in my web application and it is hosted on IIS 7.5.

I am using Windows 7 X64 (without SP1) and .Net 4.5 with SignalR v2.0.3.0.

If I run the web application from the IIS express it works fine and nothing hangs up but as soon as I run it from IIS 7.5 it hangs up my app. I confirm that if I disable this piece of code:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

 });
```

everything works fine. Here is the screenshots which suggests the all request go in a indefinite block state after hub is started. Even hub takes around 8-9 seconds to respond but even after that if I request a simple JPG I get nothing and goes in indefinite block state.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the application pool. I am running in Integrated mode.

[image]

This is the Hub class:

```
 public class AppHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            if (Context.User != null)
            {
                var email = Context.User.Identity.Name;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
                    userRepository.DoSomething(email, Context.ConnectionId);
                }
            }

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            if (Context.User != null)
            {
                var email = Context.User.Identity.Name;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();
                    userRepository.DoSomething1(email, Context.ConnectionId);
                }
            }

            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use `async/await`, `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait()` anywhere in the server-side code?

Comment: Well, yes the overriden methods OnConnected and OnDisconnected return Task but apart from that nowhere.

Comment: it might help if you showed the code for OnConnected and OnDisconnected.

Comment: sure. I posted it in my edit.

Comment: Does `DoSomething` return anything? Is it `async`? Does it use any `Task` objects inside?

Comment: Nope. The same code works just fine in IIS express of VS 2013. But when I host on IIS 7.5 it just hangs any further request of CSS/JS or any file for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation states that you should be using IIS express on your dev machine, because of the limit on the amount of concurrent requests

> When SignalR is hosted in IIS, the following versions are supported.
>   Note that if a client operating system is used, such as for
>   development (Windows 8 or Windows 7), full versions of IIS or Cassini
>   should not be used, since there will be a limit of 10 simultaneous
>   connections imposed, which will be reached very quickly since
>   connections are transient, frequently re-established, and are not
>   disposed immediately upon no longer being used. IIS Express should be
>   used on client operating system

Same thing with Windows 10.

taken from SignalR documentation here :
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/supported-platforms

Comment: @Aron probably a typo - fixed

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because of request execution limits on Windows 7 which limit how many concurrent requests there can be at a time before they get queued). According to this [table](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) here, IIS 7.5 has a request execution limit of 3 or even 1 depending on your OS, which is probably used up by the SignalR connection.